# Xamarin.Forms custom grid view alternate layout

Tags: gridview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding, viewmodel

I receive a list of contents from a webservice, I would like to place them in a grid that, based on a parameter, positions them on two lines or only one. I would like to use a viewmodel in order to use content binding.
I tried to use the grid span but I can not dynamically change it when the contents are bound.
This is the result I want to achieve.

[image: contents layout]

is there any way to do it?

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out FlexLayout instead of GridLayout. I've just used FlexLayout in my app and programitaclly populated it similar to your requirements. This tutorial really helped me - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng3sel_5D_0